# Trying two Link classes with Java

Tags: java

I am trying to link two files together and have one count the amount of characters and have the other one give the answer to the character counter. The first file cant have the word that is being given to be displayed as well. How would I go about doing so?

**File one**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "There isn't and exitsing output for that";
    try {
        FileReader readfile = new FileReader("resources/words.txt");
        BufferedReader readbuffer = new BufferedReader(readfile);
        Random rn = new Random();
        int lines = 0;
        while (readbuffer.readLine() != null) {lines++;}
        int answer = rn.nextInt(lines);
        System.out.println("Line " + (answer + 1));

        readfile = new FileReader("resources/words.txt");
        readbuffer = new BufferedReader(readfile);
        for (int i = 0; i < answer; i++) {
            readbuffer.readLine();
        }
        text = readbuffer.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("The specific Line is: " + text);
}
```

**File two**

```
  public class countWords
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "nose";
        int count = 0;

        //Counts each character except space
        string = string.replaceAll(" ", "");
        count = string.length();

        //Displays the total number of characters present in the given string
        System.out.println("Total number of characters in a string: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Link" meaning what, exactly? Also, what classes? All you posted is code floating outside of methods and with no context.

Comment: I just added the classes that are in the project if that helps

Comment: Why is the second one a class by itself and not a (static) method of the first class?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for the first file

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "There isn't and exitsing output for that";
    try {
        FileReader readfile = new FileReader("resources/words.txt");
        BufferedReader readbuffer = new BufferedReader(readfile);
        Random rn = new Random();
        int lines = 0;
        while (readbuffer.readLine() != null) {lines++;}
        int answer = rn.nextInt(lines);

        readfile = new FileReader("resources/words.txt");
        readbuffer = new BufferedReader(readfile);
        for (int i = 0; i < answer; i++) {
            readbuffer.readLine();
        }
        text = readbuffer.readLine();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WordCounter wc = new WordCounter(text);
    wc.removeSpaces();
    wc.count();
    int letters = wc.getCount();

    System.out.println("The amount of characters is:" + letters);
}
```

}

Got the second file

```
public class WordCounter
{

    private final String word;
    private int count = 0;

    public WordCounter(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void removeSpaces() {
        word.replaceAll(" ", "");
    }

    public void count() {
        count = word.length();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI the second class is pretty useless. You could use the string directly with the exact same effort.